# Android DatePicker How I can change the style, Dont show me the numbers?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker, fragment

[DatePicker dont show me the number that i select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiuUD.png)

Hi, I have a probleme my Datepicker look like that and I can't find a way to change it, I've tried putting a  to it but it doesn't work either

My code look like this:

```
public void showDatePicker() {
    // Initializiation
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(CreditTypeDetailActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo));


    View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_picker,null);
   dialogBuilder.setView(customView);
    final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    final DatePicker datePicker =
            (DatePicker) customView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_datepicker);
    final SimpleDateFormat dateViewFormatter =
            new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);
    final SimpleDateFormat formatter =
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);

    // Minimum date today

    datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    // View settings
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Elije la fecha deseada para la cita");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to you application theme in `styles.xml`:

```
  <item name="colorControlActivated">#000000</item>
```

It should change color of the selected circle to black(you can set any color that you need).